# How to set Facebook post to read only?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Is there a way on Facebook to block all commenting on a post, while still allow it to be read?

I have a post, whose active commenting has gotten out of control.  The post and the initial comments are valuable and I would like to keep them available for my readers/followers, but I need to stop the on-going comments completely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to prevent your friends from commenting on something they can see.

You can set audience as '*Only me*', but in that case it will be visible to you only.

Answer (score 2):

Only Facebook pages (like business/fan pages, as opposed to personal timelines) can be moderated.

If you're having a wide audience and make public posts that you want to moderate, I suggest you create such a page rather than use your personal timeline.